# Determining a cut-off value from two populations of unequal sample sizes

Tags: sample-size, method-comparison

I have two groups (healthy and disease, different sample sizes) of data, pooled from the individual subject's measurements of a certain region of the brain.  The size of the brain region may be different from each individual and the sample sizes were different in these two groups.  I have just carried out the ks.test using R on the data.  They are not normally distributed.

As such, I ended up having 2500 samples for the healthy group and 1000 samples for the disease group.

I have plotted the histogram of these two groups (using normalized counts for y axis) and they appeared to be two different distributions, with overlapping. I would like to determine the cut-off value between two groups.  What would be the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Follow the advice from @FrankHarrell in his answer. Much better than a cutoff is to describe and compare the full distributions for the two groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forcing any continuous assessment to be classified using a cutoff/threshold is ultimately non-reproducible, arbitrary, and has very low precision.  Plus if you use the data to select the cutoff you will need to bootstrap the whole process to get a reasonable measure of variability/stability.

*Natura non facit saltus* (Nature does not make jumps)
-- Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz